# I want to create a javascript function for flight path of a rocket ship

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, increment, decrement

The ship simulator must take in a string of letters(e.g "RAALALL" where R is turn right, A is Advance and L is left) that represent a planned flight path for a given rocket ship. Also L is -x, R is +x, up is -y and down is +y. The Return Value format is {x: X, y: Y, direction: 'down'}.

I tried for loop to iterate over the string given as parameter plus if and if else statement. The return expected was {x: 2, y: 1, direction = 'down'} but I got {x: 1, : 0, direction = 'left'}

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: Please specify your problem point in the code you tried to implement

Comment: Please check this code:

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_spaceship(flightParam) {
        var pathLenth = flightParam.length;
        var result ="";
        const Direction = {
              Up: 'up',
              Down: 'down',
              Left: 'left',
              Right: 'right'
        };
              current_direction = Direction.Up;
              currentX = 0;
              currentY = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < pathLength; i++) {
              if(flightParam[i] === "R") {
        cmd = flightParam[i];
        switch(cmd){
            case 'L':
                if(current_direction == Dirrection.Up) {
                    current_direction = Direction.Left;
                } else if(current_direction == Direction.Left) {
                    current_direction = Direction.Down;
                } else if(current_direction == Direction.Down) {
                    current_direction = Direction.Right;
                } else if(current_direction == Direction.Right) {
                    current_direction = Direction.Up;
                } 
                break;
            case 'R':
                if(current_direction == Direction.Up){
                    current_direction = Direction.Right;
                } else if(current_direction == Direction.Right) {
                    current_direction = Direction.Down;
                } else if(current_direction == Direction.Down) {
                    current_direction = Direction.Left;
                } else if(current_direction = Direction.Left) {
                    current_direction = Direction.Up;
                }
                break;
            case 'A':
                if(current_direction == Direction.Up) {
                    currentY -= 1;
                } else if(current_direction == Direction.Right) {
                    currentX += 1;
                } else if(current_direction == Direction.Down) {
                    currentY += 1;
                } else if(current_direction == Direction.Left) {
                    currentX -= 1;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    result = {x: " "+ currentX+ " ", y: " "+ currentY + " ", direction: " "+ current_direction + "''"};
    return result;
}

console.log(my_spaceship("RAALALL"));
console.log(my_spaceship("AAAA"));
console.log(my_spaceship(""));
console.log(my_spaceship("RAARA"));
```

Comment: Is this code part of the question? If so then it doesn't belong here as an answer. You should edit your question to include the code there. If you're looking for feedback on finished code, you should post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).